# Is there a template for Honeycomb-style custom notifications?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm trying to create a custom notification layout that looks just like a 3.0 notification, with a couple of extra things sprinkled in. More importantly, I also want to derive a Jelly Bean expanded notification on top of that.

I'd like the notification to have the same layout as a stock notification so it fits in nicely, i.e. like this (bottom image):

[image]

However, I cannot find any information about the proper dimensions and styles - what size do I need to use for the image on the left? What style for each text? What padding?

Ideally, I'd love to use something like android.R.listPreferredItemHeight for the height of the layout and the dimensions of the image, but I can't find anything that pertains to notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Notification.Builder` class which provides a convenient way to set the various fields of a Notification and generate content views using the platform's notification layout template.

See: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html

If you need to be compatible with versions prior to API level 11 then take a look at the NotificationCompat.Builder from the support library.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, but I was specifically asking about creating a custom layout so I can add a couple of extra views in. Is there a standard layout I can derive mine from?